# Windows 7 Ultimate on a netbook

Tags: windows-7, netbook

Is there any reason not to run Win7 Ultimate on a netbook - compared to the other versions of Win7?

Sorry - should have been clear in my original post. I have an MSDN sub so cost isn't a concern. I'm more concerned about performance or if another version is better suited to netbooks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference in performance between the versions (unless you count the Aero theme, but you can disable that). Ultimate just has more features, so it wouldn't make sense *not* to get it if cost isn't an issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

Cost, and maybe if you have a real low end netbook, you will not have graphics powerful enough for Aero.

At the end of the day, if not using Aero, joining a domain, or use Bitlocker (as well as a few other nice features) having Ultimate is just a name...

But, again, the only reason you would not use it is if the cost outweighs the benefits to you.

Comment: Win7 Ultimate will run just fine without Aero. If your graphics aren't powerful enough, then Aero will just be disabled and the OS will run just fine.

Comment: I know, that's why I said its pointless paying the extra if you are not going to use it!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to use some of the features of Ultimate -- such as Aero, Media Center, BitLocker, XP Mode, joining a domain -- it's probably a waste of money.  You might not even have hardware sufficient to run Aero or XP Mode, and you'd need a tuner for Media Center to be very useful.

On the other hand, BitLocker in particular is useful for portables, from a security perspective.  It can basically encrypt your hard drive contents.  But, on the other other hand, you could do that anyway with a free tool like [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).  :-)

Save your money and buy the edition that's right for you, after analyzing your needs.  Even if you need one or two of the features listed above, there may be a more appropriate version than Ultimate.  The following page at Microsoft will help you choose editions: [Which one is right for you?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/compare-editions)

Comment: Um... Aero isn't a feature that's only available in Win7 Ultimate. It's in Home Premium too.

Comment: Correct.  I wasn't pointing out the features available *only* in Ultimate, but features that aren't necessarily available in **all** versions of Win7 but that are *certainly* available in Ultimate (since it has everything.)  I wouldn't assume Win7 Home Premium as a basis for comparison.  Consider, Aero isn't in Win7 Starter Edition, which is likely to come pre-installed on many netbooks, and the OP mentioned he's looking at a netbook.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimate would be a complete waste of Money for a Netbook.  Im running it Now on my Dell Mini 10 only because its apart of the Release Candidate.  My Netbook has the GMA500 Pretty Lowend. and Areo runs fine on it.  But I Disabled it and it gave it a nice boost in performance.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Ultimate on an ASUS N10E. Runs fine with Aero, once booted.

Answer (score 0):

No reason unless you are seriously short on disk space, such as one of the early netbooks with a small solid state drive. I also got Ultimate free from a Microsoft event, and am running it in a virtual machine with no issues.

Answer (score -2):

disabling audiodg exe in windows 7 ultimate using tune up utilities makes mini netbook run faster.